# Uniqueness of weak solutions of the Hamilton-Jacobi Equation (Evans proof)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I need to prepare a small topic from Evan's Partial Differential Equations.
There are a few things I wasn't able to understand so far. I hope you can help me with these things:
Evans defines which requirements a weak solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi Equation has to fulfill and then goes on to proof it's uniqueness:

[image: Definition]

In his proof he claims inequality (43) to be true, "Verification is left as an exercise":

[image: First Problem]

But I'm not able to understand why inequality (c) should imply (43). I guess you have to use that the derivative of a convolution equals the convolution of function $u$ and the derivative of $\eta_\varepsilon$.

Furthermore I cannot see how inequality (46) is implied by (41) and (43):

[image: Second Problem]

Isn't $b_\varepsilon$ a scalar field?

I would be very happy if anyone could me, I'm really confused right now.

Comment: $b_\epsilon$ is the weak gradient of a scalar function, hence a vector field.

Comment: Do you understand what $A\leq B$ means for matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Do you mean matrix norms?

Comment: No, it's a partial order on symmetric matrices; $A\leq B$ if and only if $v^TAv \leq v^TBv$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. (c) is a discrete approximation of $v^TD^2uv$ where $v=z/|z|$. Sending the norm of $z$ to zero, (c) directly implies that $D^2u\leq C(1+1/s)I$, provided $u$ is $C^2$ (which it is not). So you just have to apply this argument to $u_\epsilon$ instead, which is smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you tell me how to prove that (c) is a discrete approximation of $v^T D^2 uv$?